# Change date format

Tags: loop, date

I am using wordpress for an integration with an recruitment software. Now i am having an issue with an 'endDate' slug. The date format seems to show up as yyyy-mm-dd. How can i change this format to dd-mm-yyyy

Here is the code i am using in the loop.php

```
<span class="closes-from">
            <?php
                    $post_meta_data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
                    echo ('Submission deadline: ').$post_meta_data['endDate'][0];
                    ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `strtotime()` with `Date()` to make your own date format

If you already know the meta key that you need you can do the following

```
$post_meta_data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'endDate', true);
```

See [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) for more information about the function.

Now that we have the value and going your format all you need to do is the following

```
$new_format = Date('d-m-Y', strtotime($post_meta_data));
```

> EDIT

echoing the new format.
I removed the `(` `)` because they are not needed for echoing string;

```
echo 'Submission deadline: ' . $new_format;
```

The whole code combined

```
<span class="closes-from">
    <?php
    // get end date (maybe change $post_meta_data to a more appropriate name)
    $post_meta_data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'endDate', true);

    // create a new date format
    $new_format = Date('d-m-Y', strtotime($post_meta_data));

    // output the new date format with some text
    echo 'Submission deadline: ' . $new_format;
    ?>
</span>
```

Comment: So how can i make it show up as the new format in the echo line?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the output with the new date format